# ios Swift SpriteKit: how to use a sprite in other functions

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created some particles animations with specific sprites which works fine if I use them in the function:

```
override init(size: CGSize)
```

I use the following lines:

```
let sheet_particles = Particles()

let particles_node = SKSpriteNode(texture: sheet_particles.particle000())
particles_node.name = kparticles
particles_node.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 500)
particles_node.zPosition = 5
background.addChild(particles_node)
particles_node.runAction(particlesAction)
```

To make them appear in my scene.

The problem I have is if I try to use them in other functions in my scene, I can not see them.

```
func panForTranslation(translation : CGPoint) {
    let position = selectedNode.position

    if selectedNode.name! == kpuzzleNodeName {
        selectedNode.position = CGPoint(x: position.x + translation.x * 2, y: position.y + translation.y * 2)


        switch selectedNode.name2 {

        case "0":
            if selectedNode.frame.intersects(NPuzzle13.frame) {
                particles_node.position = selectedNode.position

                particles_node.runAction(particlesAction)
                NPuzzle13.hidden = false
                selectedNode.removeFromParent()
        }
```

I see no particles sprite when the condition "0" happens but I see correctly the NPuzzle13. When I check the position of the particles_node node, its position is equal with the node selectedNode. All that is OK, except for the visibility of the particles... What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Pierro787, who is the background parent?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, it's the scene

Comment: very strange, have you setted the anchorPoint to anyone of your nodes?

Comment: I think the problem is I use global variables for this task. If I populate immediatly the global variable in the init code, it works fine but I populate it in another function, it doesn't work. The trick is to use an intermediate value for storage. Very strange, I don't really understand why.

Comment: If you can put some of your relevance code in a https://gist.github.com/ repository it could be more simple to debug ;)

Answer (score 0):

About zPosition seems all correct. I dont see any anchorPoint in your code.

I think your switch-case is jumped (not fired, not executed) because you check `switch selectedNode.name2` instead of `switch selectedNode.name`